# Jest - test html <details> tag with Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

I have tried to test my simple detail react component with jest, jsdom, enzyme without success. If I want to set attribute "open" of my detail component to true, then the jest will run in to Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null] error.

Following is simple version of my code

```js
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import React from 'react'

describe("Expander", () => {
  it("should render details in open status", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <details
        open={true}
      >
        <summary>Categorry</summary>
        This is content for Category
      </details>
    )
  })
})
```

The whole error traceback is like following

```
Ran all test suites matching /__tests__\/components\/product\/Expander.js/i.
  console.error
    Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null]
        at reportException (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
        at innerInvokeEventListeners (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:341:9)
        at invokeEventListeners (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
        at HTMLDetailsElementImpl._dispatch (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:205:9)
        at fireAnEvent (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/events.js:18:36)
        at HTMLDetailsElementImpl._dispatchToggleEvent (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLDetailsElement-impl.js:17:5)
        at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
        at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
        at getActiveElement (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:1449:16)
        at getActiveElementDeep (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:7767:17)
        at getSelectionInformation (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:7800:21)
        at prepareForCommit (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10163:26)
        at commitRootImpl (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23085:29)
        at unstable_runWithPriority (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
        at runWithPriority$1 (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11276:10)
        at commitRoot (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22990:3)
        at performSyncWorkOnRoot (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22329:3)
        at /Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11327:26
        at unstable_runWithPriority (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
        at runWithPriority$1 (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11276:10)
        at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11322:9)
        at flushSyncCallbackQueue (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11309:3)
        at batchedEventUpdates$1 (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22403:7)
        at batchedEventUpdates (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3745:12)
        at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8507:3)
        at attemptToDispatchEvent (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6005:3)
        at dispatchEvent (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:5924:19)
        at unstable_runWithPriority (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
        at dispatchUserBlockingUpdate (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:5894:5)
        at HTMLDivElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
        at innerInvokeEventListeners (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)
        at invokeEventListeners (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
        at HTMLDetailsElementImpl._dispatch (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:205:9)
        at fireAnEvent (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/events.js:18:36)
        at HTMLDetailsElementImpl._dispatchToggleEvent (/Users/htseng/Documents/code/store_fe/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLDetailsElement-impl.js:17:5)
        at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
        at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)

      at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
      at reportException (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:70:28)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:341:9)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLDetailsElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:205:9)
      at fireAnEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/events.js:18:36)
```

Can anyone give me advice how to solve it or suggest the reason that cause such problem? I would deeply appreciate any related information.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.